# Can you request/get variables from img src?

Tags: jquery, variables, post, image, src

This is a two part question, but I want to make sure the first is actually achievable.

Firstly, can you get access variables set by img src?  I am attempting jQuery, including MySQL UPDATE etc, but this I needed to make sure would work?

```
<a href="#" class="chnge"><img src="filename.jpg?id=1&open=1" /></a>
```

The jQuery would then have something similar to:

```
      $("img#chnge").click(function() {

        var id      = $('#id').attr('value');
        var open    = $('#open').attr('value');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "update.php",
                data: "id="+ id +"& open="+ open,
                success: function(){
                    $('img#chnge').fadeTo('slow',0.4);

                }
            });
        return false;
        });
```

I hope it is obvious, basically, I have an image, if it's "open" is set to 1, when you click it the opacity changes, but it would also send off a query to my update.php.

I know where the errors are in this form, I just dont know how to fix them.  #1 = variables in the img src (i dont know if i can put them in the href instead?), and the 2nd is the $('#id') and $('#open') I don't think are correct, but I don't know what to change them to either.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Phillip.

UPDATE: After reading Otars reply, I thought I had better add the full code re: how the images are to be where they are...

Thank-you.  Because these images are being generated through a for() loop (php), is that going to have an affect on how this code will work?

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalogue");
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);

for ($x=1;$x<=$num;$x++) {

  $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);

  ?>

  <a href="#" id="chngeHref" /><img src="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>?id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>&open=<?php echo $row[1]; ?>" id="chnge" /></a>

<?php

  /* row[0] = id 
     row[1] = open (1 or 0)
     row[2] = image url
  */

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway your image has to be a PHP script...

Pass GET parameters to it, do whatever you want in the script and then output the image like this:

Let's say file is called `image.php`

```
<?php

    $par = $_GET['test'];

    // Do some PHP related job here


    // Load the image
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header('Location: /path/to/your/image.jpg');

?>
```

Then use it like this: `<img src="image.php?test=value">`

It gonna call the PHP script first and then display image.

Comment: Thank-you, this has allowed me to add variables to the image.  I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: what if you need 10 images from a PHP file? (what changes you should apply to PHP and JQuery script to be able to get 10 images from the php file?)

Comment: @Shadi Pass image URL as a script parameter `<img src="image.php?img=/path/to/your/image.jpg&test=value">` and modify redirection header like this: `header('Location: ' . $_GET['img']);`. Please make sure you validate/secure/escape passed parameter...

Comment: Thank you, but using this solution, again 'image.php' is sending only one image to the html file. I need php to send more than one. something like:    header('Location: /path/to/your/image1.jpg');    header('Location: /path/to/your/image2.jpg');    header('Location: /path/to/your/image3.jpg');       and then in html: <img src="image.php, image1">    <img src="image.php, image2">   <img src="image.php, image3">

Comment: @Shadi How do you imagine displaying several images in one `<img>` tag? That's far from the HTML possibilities... Why would you need to use something like that?

Comment: No, I need different images in different image tags. for example, I want to receive 3 images from the server and display them in 3 different places in my page. (the position of pictures in the page will be specified by the client-side code, but the images will be created by the server). Thanks.

Comment: @Shadi Then the method I told you perfectly matches you needs. `<img src="image.php?img=image1.jpg">` `<img src="image.php?img=image2.jpg">` `<img src="image.php?img=image3.jpg">`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't exactly understand what your trying to do, but think this might help. You can store the images "open" state as a variable inside $(function(){..}). You will then be able to get and set that variable value from within your click event.

```
$(function() {

    var open = false; // store the image state in the closure not global
    var id = .. 

    $(".chnge img").click(function() {
        if (!open) {
            // fade-in, post to server or whatever

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "update.php",
                data: "id="+ id +"& open="+ open,
                success: function(){
                    // handle response here.
                    // you can still access the open variable here!
                }
            }

            open = true; // want to update open?
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont understand the language enough to know if this would work... haha.  Or how to implement it.  Thankyou for your input! :D

Comment: could you please explain your answer a little more? for example, what is the content of php file and the success:function()? Thanks in advance.